# Adding multiple form elements to a form

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write some javascript to allow me to click on a link which will add a row of form elements to a html page. It is basically a page to add names to a page and submit them.

The form layout is [Title] [Firstname] [Lastname]

I need to be able to add a new row and delete any row from the list dynamically.

Can anyone help me with this as im totally lost with javascript :(

Thank you in advance for any help given :)

Comment: You have to show some code and your HTML if you want us to help you.

Comment: sorry thats what im asking where do i start, is there any existing code i can use etc...

Comment: Then you should start reading a JavaScript tutorial first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use kQuery `append()` or `appendTo()`. For more info : http://api.jquery.com/.

```
$('<td><input /><input /><input /></td>').insertAfter("#idTable>tr:last);
```

That should go the trick !

Comment: Perfect I had totally forgotten about jquery :) Will take a look now.